# NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Estou tentando passar informações de uma `Activity` para outra através da posição na lista, mas está dando esse erro de `nullpointer`.

**Onde pego as informações - Activity Principal**

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);


    Intent intent = new Intent(PrincipalActivity.this, ListaPermissoesActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
    String nome = carrega_container.getNomeApp(position);
    String msg = carrega_container.getPermissoes(position);
    bundle.putString("nome", nome);
    bundle.putString("msg", msg);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Abrindo informaçoes...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 }
```

**Activity que deveria receber as informações** (o erro deve ser aqui)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_permissoes);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();


    String nome = bundle.getString("nome");
    TextView appNome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nome_app);
    appNome.setText(nome);
    setContentView(appNome);

    String msg = bundle.getString("msg");
    TextView appPermissao = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_lista);
    appPermissao.setText(msg);
    setContentView(appPermissao);
}
```

O nome nos xmls estão corretos.

**Erro**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.android.br.listadeaplicativos, PID: 5113
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.br.listadeaplicativos/com.android.br.listadeaplicativos.ListaPermissoesActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.app.Activity.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.app.Activity.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                  at com.android.br.listadeaplicativos.ListaPermissoesActivity.onCreate(ListaPermissoesActivity.java:28)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Por que tem dois `setContentView()`?

Comment: O problema é que a variável `view` no evento `onCreate` está nulo. De onde vem este valor?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver, eu removi os outros dois `setContentView()` e os `view` antes dos `findViewById`